# Can a user be given read only access to all items when Item-level Permissions are enabled?

Tags: permissions, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, item-level-permissions, read-only

In a list with these settings:

- Read items that were created by the user
- Create items and edit items that were created by the user

Is it possible to grant **read only** permission to view all items?

End users should only see only their own items, but we have group that should not be able to edit but still needs needs read access to all items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but to view all items with those settings you need to be an "Approver" on the list.

The default Approver group includes Edit/Delete access, but you might be able to create an "ApproverOnly" group (name it whatever you want), that is limited to Approving, Viewing, etc... but not Editing and Deleting items.

Again, haven't tried it, but it might work?

Good luck!

Comment: Seems like this works!

Specifically you grant the "Override List Behaviors" permission level which requires view but does not require edit permissions.

Comment: Perfect, Thank You @Chad! Also thanks @Jane Panda for useful comment!